# Django Rest Framework sets related serializer field to null on save for no reason

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

django==1.9.10
djangorestframework==3.4.7

Here are the models.

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Form(models.Model):
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Here are the serializers.

```
class FormShortSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = ('url',)

class DealerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    forms = FormShortSerializer(source='form_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
```

Here are the viewsets.

```
class DealerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Dealer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DealerSerializer

class FormViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Form.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FormSerializer
```

So, the API response for Dealer URL is this.

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/rest-api/dealer/1/",
    "forms": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/rest-api/form/1/"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/rest-api/form/2/"
        }
    ],
    "first_name": "First Name"
}
```

But, when I do **PATCH** to this URL, say, updating the `first_name` to something else, for some reason DRF sets `dealer` field on all forms to `null`, and the response looks like this.

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/rest-api/dealer/1/",
    "forms": [],  # Forms are empty.
    "first_name": "Changed Name"  # Name changed.
}
```

Any idea why guys? None of the models overload `save` methods or doing any magic behind the scenes. Only `Meta` class `__unicode__` methods are defined there, but I think it's irrelevant here, so I haven't included it in the code.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Which version of DRF are you using? Can you paste here body of PATCH request you are trying?

Comment: The version is 3.4.7

Comment: PATCH body: `{"first_name": "Changed Name"}`

Comment: do you need to change the `form` from `DealerSerializer`? if not, recommend you to set read_only to true like this: `forms = FormShortSerializer(source='form_set', many=True, read_only=True)`

Comment: I don't, and yes that's a good option. Thank you. But still, I wonder why it happens.